# Hibernate validation message from properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I am trying to get a custom message from property file, but I can't.
My configs:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/ValidationMessages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Class which must be valid:

```
public class NewUserDto {
    @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.newUserDto.email}")
    private String email;
}
```

Value in my property file: `NotEmpty.newUserDto.email = Some value.`
But instead `Some value` I get `{NotEmpty.newUserDto.email}`, why it is so?

Comment: could you check whether `messageSource` has any values using debugger

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to inject a String message from properties file, which in it, you have an entry of:

`NotEmpty.newUserDto.email`

And it got a value that should act as your message error in case of bean validation failure.

In this case:

First, use expression language to inject the property. like this:

```
@Component
public class NewUserDto {
    @Value("${NotEmpty.newUserDto.email}")
    private String msg;

    @NotEmpty(message = msg)
    private String email;
}
```

Don't forget to annotate your class with `@Component` annotation and turn it to bean in order to do this `@Value` injection. of course, you'll have to add to your configuration file the next:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.to.NewUserDto" />
```

You can try to do it directly, like this:

```
@Component
public class NewUserDto {

    @NotEmpty(message = @Value("${NotEmpty.newUserDto.email}"))
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: Yes, its probably will works, but I think it is not an effective solution.

Comment: Because I have to add extra fields in my DTO class. And I don't want my DTOs are `@Component`

Comment: Look at the edit solution, try to do the injection directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java configuration. You can refer to the below example:

Delcare a bean like this

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {     

    @Email @NotEmpty
    private String email;
}
```

A custom message is located in a file messages.properties

```
Email.employee.email=Please provide a valid Email address
```

and this file is added in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I found this example from the post [Spring MVC Form Validation Annotation Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/spring-mvc-form-validation-annotation-example.html)

Comment: Where do you placed your properties file?

Comment: classpath: resources/messages